# grep command to display lines with leading and trailing blanks

Tags: unix

I have a test folder that contains some text:

```
1  Line one. $
2      Line $
3 This is a new line $
4 This is the same line$
5                 $
```

How would I go about using a PIPED grep command to only displays lines 1, 2 and 5?
My attempt at this was `grep -n '^ ' test | grep -n ' $' test`
However I get lines 1, 2, 3, 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `grep` innvocation in the pipe reads the file `test` and ignores the pipe. The first `grep` writes to the pipe, but its output is discarded. So, your command effectively is identical to

```
grep -n ' $' test
```

Just remove the `test` argument from the second `grep` invocation.

You are probably better off removing the `-n` option there as well, because it will count the lines it reads from the pipe then, which is probably not what you want.